# HeatMap / Histogram Chart in Chart.js

Tags: chart.js, chart.js2

How to create histogram / heat map chart like the snapshot in chart.js.

Requirement is to plot days of week on x axis (Sun, Mon, Tues) and time in hour on y axis (1-12 or 24). All the values will be shown in the color range lighter to darker [image]

Comment: You'll need the plugin http://tmroyal.github.io/Chart.HeatMap/

Comment: Seems like the library is no longer maintained. Any other alternative?

Comment: @Madhavi - yes, the original dev of that lib actually names a few in his github: https://github.com/tmroyal/Chart.HeatMap/#better-alternatives